# Object Pool implementation using blocking queue

Tags: java, multithreading

> You need to design and implement a generic pool for storing objects (implementing poolable). The pool should support the following:
>
> 1. A support for creational pattern which would be used by the pool to create objects automatically when needed
> 2. Maximum and Minimum number of objects which can be created and made available within the pool. Minimum number would be used to make sure that the number of objects are available in the pool, Maximum number would make sure that the pool will create a max of these objects
> 3. Automatic clearing of objects not used in the pool, this clearing agent can run at a fixed time interval
> 4. Once the object borrowed from the pool is used should support returning back

```
package com.tripplepoint.codingassignment.objectpool;

import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class ObjectPool<T extends Poolable> implements ObjectPoolable<T> {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ObjectPool.class
            .getCanonicalName());

    private final BlockingQueue<T> pool;
    /** Maximum number of connections that the pool can have */
    private final int maxPoolSize;
    /** Number of connections that should be created initially */
    private final int minPoolSize;
    /** Indicates weather shutdown is called or not */
    volatile private boolean shutdownCalled;
    // fine grained locking
    private final Lock takeLock = new ReentrantLock();
    private final Lock releseLock = new ReentrantLock();

    /**
     * after allocationTrigeerInterval time thread will check the pool and
     * depends on necessity it will create or discard the object from the pool.
     */
    private final long allocationTrigeerInterval;
    private final TimeUnit timeUnit1;
    private ScheduledExecutorService executorService;

    private long nextAllocationTrigeerInterval;

    /**  Count the number get Request for an interval    */
    private AtomicInteger takeRate = new AtomicInteger(0);
    /**  Count the number Released object for an interval    */
    private AtomicInteger releaseRate = new AtomicInteger(0);

    /**
     * Object Factory to create the object of poolable type
     */
    private ObjectFactory<T> objectFactory;

    public ObjectPool(int maxPoolSize, int minPoolSize,
            ObjectFactory<T> objectFactory, long allocationTrigeerInterval,
            TimeUnit timeUnit1) {

        if ((minPoolSize > maxPoolSize) || minPoolSize < 1 || maxPoolSize < 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid pool size parameters");
        }

        this.maxPoolSize = maxPoolSize;
        this.minPoolSize = minPoolSize;
        this.objectFactory = objectFactory;
        this.pool = new LinkedBlockingQueue<T>(maxPoolSize);
        this.shutdownCalled = false;
        this.allocationTrigeerInterval = allocationTrigeerInterval;
        this.nextAllocationTrigeerInterval = allocationTrigeerInterval;
        this.timeUnit1 = timeUnit1;
        initialize();

        if (pool.size() != minPoolSize) {
            logger.log(
                    Level.WARNING,
                    "Initial sized pool creation failed. InitializedPoolSize={0}, minPoolSize={1}",
                    new Object[] { pool.size(), minPoolSize });
        }
    }

    protected void initialize() {
        for (int i = 0; i < minPoolSize; i++) {
            createandPoolObject();
        }
        /**
         * creating separate thread to monitor the pool size 1. If there are
         * less object inside the pool than minPoolSize then it will create new
         * objects inside the pool 2. If there are more objects than minPoolSize
         * then it will remove the objects from the pool
         */

        executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

        executorService.scheduleWithFixedDelay(()-> {
                try {
                    int poolSize = pool.size();
                    int takerate = takeRate.get();
                    //TODO  nextAllocationTrigeerInterval  will not updated for the next scheduled run :Need to change the logic probably 
                    nextAllocationTrigeerInterval = (((poolSize - takerate) / (takerate - releaseRate.get())) + 1) * nextAllocationTrigeerInterval;
                    // Reset the rate 
                    takeRate.set(0);
                    releaseRate.set(0);
                    if (poolSize < minPoolSize) {
                        int sizeToBeAdded = minPoolSize - poolSize;
                        for (int i = 0; i < sizeToBeAdded; i++) {
                            createandPoolObject();
                        }
                    } else if (poolSize > minPoolSize) {
                        int sizeTobeRemoved = poolSize - minPoolSize;
                        for (int i = 0; i < sizeTobeRemoved; i++) {
                            removeObjectfromPool();
                        }
                    }
                } catch (IllegalStateException excep) {
                    logger.log(
                            Level.FINEST,
                            "Shutdown is called , so no need of create/discard the object from the pool",
                            new Object[] { excep.toString() });
                }
        }, allocationTrigeerInterval, nextAllocationTrigeerInterval, timeUnit1);
    }

    /**
     * This method create the poolable object and and into the pool.
     */
    private void createandPoolObject() {
        if (!shutdownCalled) {
            T poolObject = null;
            try {
                poolObject = objectFactory.newInstance();
            } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
                logger.log(Level.WARNING,
                        "Object Creation failed with exception ={0}",
                        new Object[] { e.getMessage() });
                return;
            }
            pool.offer(poolObject);
            logger.log(
                    Level.FINE,
                    "Created Poolable {0}, currentPoolSize={1}, maxPoolSize={2}",
                    new Object[] { poolObject.toString(), pool.size(),
                            maxPoolSize });
        } else {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Object Pool is already shoudown");
        }

    }

    private void removeObjectfromPool() {
        if (!shutdownCalled) {
            pool.remove();
        } else {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Object Pool is already shoudown");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Borrowed thread will be blocked till the poolable object will be
     * available in the pool.
     * 
     * @return
     * @throws InterruptedException
     */
    public T getObject() throws InterruptedException {
        T obj = null;

        if (!shutdownCalled) {
            takeLock.lock();            
            try {
                obj = pool.take();
                takeRate.incrementAndGet();
            } finally {
                takeLock.unlock();
            }

            logger.log(Level.FINEST, "get Object from Pool Object{0}",
                    new Object[] { obj.toString() });
        } else {

            throw new IllegalStateException("Object Pool is already shoudown");

        }

        return obj;

    }

    /**
     * This method will wait for defined time if there is no poolable object in
     * the pool
     * 
     * @param timeOut
     * @param timeUnit
     * @return
     * @throws InterruptedException
     */

    public T getObject(long timeOut, TimeUnit timeUnit)
            throws InterruptedException {
        T obj = null;

        if (!shutdownCalled) {
            takeLock.lock();            
            try {
                obj = pool.poll(timeOut, timeUnit);
                takeRate.incrementAndGet();
            } finally {
                takeLock.unlock();
            }

            logger.log(Level.FINEST, "get Object from Pool Object{0}",
                    new Object[] { obj.toString() });
        } else {

            throw new IllegalStateException("Object Pool is already shoudown");

        }

        return obj;
    }

    /**
     * Surrender thread will block if the pool is exceeding the max size of the
     * pool
     * 
     * @param t
     * @throws InterruptedException
     */

    public void release(T t) throws InterruptedException {

        if (!shutdownCalled) {
            releseLock.lock();          
            try {
                pool.put(t);
                releaseRate.incrementAndGet();
            } finally {
                releseLock.unlock();
            }

            logger.log(Level.FINEST, "Releases Pool Object{0}",
                    new Object[] { t.toString() });

        } else {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Object Pool is already shoudown");

        }

    }

    /**
     * Surrender thread will wait for defined time if Object pool is full
     * 
     * @param poolable
     *            object
     * @throws InterruptedException
     */

    public void release(T t, long timeOut, TimeUnit timeUnit)
            throws InterruptedException {

        if (!shutdownCalled) {
            releseLock.lock();          
            try {
                pool.offer(t, timeOut, timeUnit);
                releaseRate.incrementAndGet();
            } finally {
                releseLock.unlock();
            }
            logger.log(Level.FINEST, "Release Pool Object{0}",
                    new Object[] { t.toString() });

        } else {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Object Pool is already shoudown");

        }

    }

    /**
     * After calling this method it will not accept any more request It will
     * process queued request and clear the pool
     */

    public synchronized void shutdown() {
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "Object pool shutdown started...");
        shutdownCalled = true;
        takeLock.lock(); // waiting for get and release operation to finish
        releseLock.lock();
        try {
            pool.stream().forEach((t) -> t.close());
            pool.clear();
            executorService.shutdown();
        } finally {
            releseLock.unlock();
            takeLock.unlock();
        }
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "Object pool shutdown completed...");
    }

    /**
     * return the number of Objects in the pool
     */

    public int getPoolSize() {
        // waiting for get and release operation to finish
        takeLock.lock();
        releseLock.lock();
        try {

            return pool.size();
        } finally {
            releseLock.unlock();
            takeLock.unlock();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi, as your question starts with a block of code instead of regular text, on the [front page](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions) it shows up with "..." as the summary. That's not very attractive to reviewers. It would be better to add a nice introductory paragraph that briefly explains what the code does. See also [this meta post](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/2436/how-to-get-the-best-value-out-of-code-review-asking-questions) to make the most out of asking questions here.

Comment: What are `Poolable` and `ObjectPoolable` ?

Comment: ObjectFactoryImpl  Is this implementation provides the intended use of soft References ?.

Answer (score 3):

You use lock locks in the get and release methods. This somewhat defeats the purpose of using the threadsafe pool. The getPoolSize doesn't need to wait on finishing the get or release as `pool.size()` is thread-safe and the pool's size is fluid anyway when multiple threads are contesting over it.

For shutdown you can use `pool.drainTo` to clear the pool to another collection when shutting down:

```
executorService.shutdown(); //first to stop the creation thread
List<T> list = new ArrayList<>(pool.size()+10);
pool.drainTo(list);
list.stream().forEach((t) -> t.close());
```

That means you can remove the locks as the pool will take care of the thread-safety.

---

`shutdown` is declared synchronized but that it the only method that is. But there is no protection against calling it twice in a row, nor do any of the operations need to be guarded like that.

---

I would also add a third `getObject` variant that will create an object on the calling thread when the pool is empty.

```
public T getOrCreateObject()
        throws InterruptedException {
    T obj = null;

    if (!shutdownCalled) {

        obj = pool.poll();
        if(obj == null){
            obj = objectFactory.newInstance();
        }
        takeRate.incrementAndGet();

        logger.log(Level.FINEST, "get Object from Pool Object{0}",
                new Object[] { obj.toString() });
    } else {

        throw new IllegalStateException("Object Pool is already shoudown");

    }

    return obj;
}
```

---

The creation task checks `if (poolSize > minPoolSize)` I think you mean `maxPoolSize` there.

Release shouldn't be blocking. Instead if the pool is full just discard the object.

```
public void release(T t) throws InterruptedException {

    if (!shutdownCalled) {

        if(!pool.offer(t))t.close();
        releaseRate.incrementAndGet();

        logger.log(Level.FINEST, "Releases Pool Object{0}",
                new Object[] { t.toString() });

    } else {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Object Pool is already shoudown");

    }

}
```

`removeObjectfromPool` doesn't call `close` on the discarded object.

Comment: Shutdown Method :  drainTo   1. Is it thread safe as bulk operation on collection are not thread safe . 2. Does it permits the take, release other operations  after calling the drainTo ?  Is it atomic operation ?  This information will help to decide 1. shutDownCalled variable to be maintain or not.  2. Does it require to acquire the locks before calling  pool.clear.

Comment: Java Specification : Removes all available elements from this queue and adds them to the given collection. This operation may be more efficient than repeatedly polling this queue. A failure encountered while attempting to add elements to collection c may result in elements being in neither, either or both collections when the associated exception is thrown. Attempts to drain a queue to itself result in IllegalArgumentException. Further, the behavior of this operation is undefined if the specified collection is modified while the operation is in progress.

Comment: get and relese method with lock defeats the purpose of using thread safe linkedblocking queue
      But to make the following operation atomic need to use the lock
      obj = pool.take();
      takeRate.incrementAndGet();
       otherwise takerate will not consistent

Comment: This API have two overloaded method One is getObject blocking and another one is non-blocking wait for certain time. 
     These two methods using the same lock, so there is possibility of non-blocking method will behave like blocking
     What would be the appropriate solution for this ?
      having another lock, these leads too many locks as in future if need to support other versions of getObject  
      and shutdown becomes costly as need to acquire too many locks.

Comment: if (poolSize > minPoolSize) this is correct as per the problem statement.

Comment: Soft references highly useful in creating object pools, where the size of the pool needs to be dynamic. If you do not know the size of a pool when you begin, or choose not to set a minimum or a maximum size on the object pool, instead you want it to grow dynamically, and at the same time, you want to give the JVM a chance to cleanup unused objects, in that case SoftReferences are a perfect fit. So deciding to use this.

Comment: Adding to an arraylist will never fail. So that part of drainTo does not apply.

Comment: takeRate doesn't need to be exact, just near enough. You can use getAndSet to get the current take rate and reset it to 0 atomically.

Answer (score -1):

1. Return the `softReference` from the object factory
2. Store the `SoftReference` in the Pool
3. Made the code changes by considering the comments posted earlier

---

```
package com.tripplepoint.codingassignment.objectpool;

import java.lang.ref.SoftReference;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class ObjectPool<T extends Poolable> implements ObjectPoolable<T> {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ObjectPool.class
            .getCanonicalName());

    private final BlockingQueue<SoftReference<T>> pool;
    /** Maximum number of connections that the pool can have */
    private final int maxPoolSize;
    /** Number of connections that should be created initially */
    private final int minPoolSize;
    /** Indicates weather shutdown is called or not */
    volatile private boolean shutdownCalled;
    // fine grained locking
    private final Lock takeLock = new ReentrantLock();
    private final Lock releseLock = new ReentrantLock();

    /**
     * after allocationTrigeerInterval time thread will check the pool and
     * depends on necessity it will create or discard the object from the pool.
     */
    private final long allocationTrigeerInterval;
    private final TimeUnit timeUnit1;
    private ScheduledExecutorService executorService;

    private long nextAllocationTrigeerInterval;

    /** Count the number get Request for an interval */
    private AtomicInteger takeRate = new AtomicInteger(0);
    /** Count the number Released object for an interval */
    private AtomicInteger releaseRate = new AtomicInteger(0);

    /**
     * Object Factory to create the object of poolable type
     */
    private ObjectFactory<T> objectFactory;

    public ObjectPool(int maxPoolSize, int minPoolSize,
            ObjectFactory<T> objectFactory, long allocationTrigeerInterval,
            TimeUnit timeUnit1) {

        if ((minPoolSize > maxPoolSize) || minPoolSize < 1 || maxPoolSize < 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid pool size parameters");
        }

        this.maxPoolSize = maxPoolSize;
        this.minPoolSize = minPoolSize;
        this.objectFactory = objectFactory;
        this.pool = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(maxPoolSize);
        this.shutdownCalled = false;
        this.allocationTrigeerInterval = allocationTrigeerInterval;
        this.nextAllocationTrigeerInterval = allocationTrigeerInterval;
        this.timeUnit1 = timeUnit1;
        initialize();

        if (pool.size() != minPoolSize) {
            logger.log(
                    Level.WARNING,
                    "Initial sized pool creation failed. InitializedPoolSize={0}, minPoolSize={1}",
                    new Object[] { pool.size(), minPoolSize });
        }
    }

    protected void initialize() {
        for (int i = 0; i < minPoolSize; i++) {
            createandPoolObject();
        }
        /**
         * creating separate thread to monitor the pool size 1. If there are
         * less object inside the pool than minPoolSize then it will create new
         * objects inside the pool 2. If there are more objects than minPoolSize
         * then it will remove the objects from the pool
         */

        executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

        executorService
                .scheduleWithFixedDelay(
                        () -> {
                            try {
                                int poolSize = pool.size();
                                int takerate = takeRate.getAndSet(0);
                                // TODO nextAllocationTrigeerInterval will not
                                // updated for the next scheduled run :Need to
                                // change the logic
                                nextAllocationTrigeerInterval = (((poolSize - takerate) / (takerate - releaseRate
                                        .getAndSet(0))) + 1)
                                        * nextAllocationTrigeerInterval;

                                if (poolSize < minPoolSize) {
                                    int sizeToBeAdded = minPoolSize - poolSize;
                                    for (int i = 0; i <= sizeToBeAdded; i++) {
                                        createandPoolObject();
                                    }
                                } else if (poolSize > minPoolSize) {
                                    int sizeTobeRemoved = poolSize
                                            - minPoolSize;
                                    for (int i = 0; i <= sizeTobeRemoved; i++) {
                                        removeObjectfromPool();
                                    }
                                }
                            } catch (IllegalStateException excep) {
                                logger.log(
                                        Level.FINEST,
                                        "Shutdown is called , so no need of create/discard the object from the pool",
                                        new Object[] { excep.toString() });
                            }
                        }, allocationTrigeerInterval,
                        nextAllocationTrigeerInterval,
                        timeUnit1);
    }

    /**
     * This method create the poolable object and and into the pool.
     */
    private void createandPoolObject() {
        if (!shutdownCalled) {
            SoftReference<T> poolObject = null;
            try {
                poolObject = objectFactory.newInstance();
            } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
                logger.log(Level.WARNING,
                        "Object Creation failed with exception ={0}",
                        new Object[] { e.getMessage() });
                return;
            }
            pool.offer(poolObject);
            logger.log(
                    Level.FINE,
                    "Created Poolable {0}, currentPoolSize={1}, maxPoolSize={2}",
                    new Object[] { poolObject.toString(), pool.size(),
                            maxPoolSize });
        } else {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Object Pool is already shoudown");
        }

    }

    private void removeObjectfromPool() {
        if (!shutdownCalled) {
            pool.remove();
        } else {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Object Pool is already shoudown");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Borrowed thread will be blocked till the poolable object will be
     * available in the pool.
     * 
     * @return
     * @throws InterruptedException
     */
    public T getObject() throws InterruptedException {
        T obj = null;

        if (!shutdownCalled) {
            takeLock.lock();
            try {
                obj = pool.take().get();
                takeRate.incrementAndGet();
            } finally {
                takeLock.unlock();
            }

            logger.log(Level.FINEST, "get Object from Pool Object{0}",
                    new Object[] { obj.toString() });
        } else {

            throw new IllegalStateException("Object Pool is already shoudown");

        }

        return obj;

    }

    /**
     * TO-DO this method will act as blocked in case where no element in queue
     * take is called and after that this method get called ? This method will
     * wait for defined time if there is no poolable object in the pool
     * 
     * @param timeOut
     * @param timeUnit
     * @return
     * @throws InterruptedException
     */

    public T getObject(long timeOut, TimeUnit timeUnit)
            throws InterruptedException {
        T obj = null;

        if (!shutdownCalled) {
            takeLock.lock();
            try {
                obj = pool.poll(timeOut, timeUnit).get();
                takeRate.incrementAndGet();
            } finally {
                takeLock.unlock();
            }

            logger.log(Level.FINEST, "get Object from Pool Object{0}",
                    new Object[] { obj.toString() });
        } else {

            throw new IllegalStateException("Object Pool is already shoudown");

        }

        return obj;
    }

    /**
     * This method will add the object in to the pool if size is not full If
     * size is full then it will discards object by performing clean up
     * activity.
     * 
     * @param t
     * @throws InterruptedException
     */

    public void release(T t) throws InterruptedException {

        if (!shutdownCalled) {
            releseLock.lock();
            try {
                if (!pool.offer(new SoftReference<T>(t))) {
                    t.close();
                }
                releaseRate.incrementAndGet();
            } finally {
                releseLock.unlock();
            }

            logger.log(Level.FINEST, "Releases Pool Object{0}",
                    new Object[] { t.toString() });

        } else {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Object Pool is already shoudown");

        }

    }

    /**
     * After calling this method it will not accept any more request It will
     * process queued request and clear the pool
     */

    public void shutdown() {
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "Object pool shutdown started...");
        if (!shutdownCalled) {
            shutdownCalled = true;
            List<SoftReference<T>> list = new ArrayList<>(maxPoolSize);
            takeLock.lock(); // waiting for get and release operation to finish
            releseLock.lock();
            try {
                executorService.shutdown();// First stop the creation of thread
                pool.drainTo(list); // TODO Not sure of thread safety
                list.stream().forEach((t) -> t.get().close());
                list.clear();
                pool.clear();
            } finally {
                releseLock.unlock();
                takeLock.unlock();
            }
            logger.log(Level.INFO, "Object pool shutdown completed...");

        } else {
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "Other thread as alreday called shutdown...");
        }
    }

    /**
     * return the number of Objects in the pool
     */

    public int getPoolSize() {
            return pool.size();

    }

}
```